# Close active modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap-modal

I have opened multiple modals in my angular project. I have made a modal component as wrapper for the content. Now I want to close the active modal instead of closing all modals. So the dismissAll need to be replaced. I have in mind to use ***NgbActiveModal*** but get an error as soon as I add this to the constructor.

The error message as appears in the browser

> *ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NgbActiveModal -> NgbActiveModal -> NgbActiveModal]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal!
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NgbActiveModal -> NgbActiveModal -> NgbActiveModal]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal!*

How to solve this?

My code

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {faTimes} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent {
    @Input() titel: string = 'Editor';
    @Input() popupClass: string;
    @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
    cross = faTimes;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
                private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
    }

    open() {
        this.modalService.open(this.content,
        {   ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',
                        windowClass: this.popupClass
                }).result.then((result) => {}, (reason) => {
        });
    }

    close() {
        this.modalService.dismissAll()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NgbActiveModal is only provided if you are passing a Component as the argument to the open() call.

You can either call the open function passing ModalComponent as your the fist argument:

```
this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, ...)
```

Or you need to use the open's call return value to close your modal by passing it as an @Input() to the component inside your 'content' that will be handling the close event. Something like this:

In your ModalComponent:

```
this.modalRef = this.open(this.content,...);
```

In your template:

```
<div #content>
    <some-child-component [modalRef]="modalRef"></some-child-component>
</div>
```

And the use the modalRef.close() in your code in the some-child-component.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a ref to the currently opened modal and close only that one:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent {
    @Input() titel: string = 'Editor';
    @Input() popupClass: string;
    @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
    cross = faTimes;
    private modalRef: any;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
    }

    open() {
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.content,
        {   ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',
                        windowClass: this.popupClass
                }).result.then((result) => {}, (reason) => {
        });
    }

    close() {
        this.modalService.close(this.modalRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but NgbModal does not have the close method. Only dismissAll is available. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can't figure it out, it's always a good idea to [have a look at the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngb-modal).